# How to accurately calculate person's age in a perform screen

Tags: informix, date-arithmetic, date

Informix-SE 4.10 with isql 4.10 DD6:

I have a DATE column, BirthDate, linked to a perform field tag "dob". When users enter the dob, I am doing the following date arithmetic:

```
age = (TODAY - dob ) / 365.25
```

field tag age is DISPLAYONLY TYPE DECIMAL field, with FORMAT="##.##".

This method is not producing accurate results.

Business Rule: Example, If a person true age is not 18 years old the day before their 18th birthday, I need to display 17 in the age field tag, and abort insertion of the customer row. Person must be >=18 years old.

DATETIME and INTERVAL datatypes are supported in this ifx version, but users are only comfortable entering dates in MMDDYYYY format.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to use the condition `dob <= MDY(MONTH(TODAY), DAY(TODAY), YEAR(TODAY) - 18)` (born at least 18 years ago) as the condition, with some choice of comparator, depending on whether you're looking for valid or invalid DoB?  This could only fail on 29th February; with SE and ISQL 4.10, the calculation will fail on 29th February. Dates are so messy, regardless.  Modern Informix would handle that calculation, defaulting to 28th February of 18 years ago.  And that's before we get to issues of whether that calculation can be done in Perform.

Comment: @Jonathan, if SE 4.10 DATE and DATETIME arithmetic accurately returns the number of days between two dates, why would a February 29th birthday test fail?

Comment: @Jonathan, DATE columns do not allow users to enter invalid dates in perform. I am also wondering if doing a lookup on a DOB dimension table could be a solution, since date functions, like MDY, are not supported in 4.10 perform screens.

Comment: The problem is that if today is the 29th of February, then 18 years ago today was not the 29th of February.  And my calculation was based on that.  I'd use I4GL or add C to Perform to get this job done, but that's not trivial when you're stuck on DOS.  Yes, a lookup might be appropriate — at worst, for each given date, what's the maximum (most recent) DoB that can be allowed.  Generating that table is trivial, of course; using it, a little harder.  It'd be easy enough to show the most recent DoB that's allowed.

Comment: Understood about FEB-29th's. It's ironic how this is so trivial in real life, yet non-trivial for a legacy db engine to solve. Can a decimal value like 17.95 be displayed as 17 in an INT or SMALLINT displayonly field?

Comment: Does `PICTURE = "##"` not work?

Comment: Nope, it's rounding 17.95 to 18 when displayonly field is DECIMAL, SMALLINT and INT.

Comment: I am going to try displayonly CHAR(2) to see if it will truncate the decimals.

Comment: Casting age calc result to char(2) displayonly field also rounded 17.95 to 18, so I used ifx 11.70 TC5 to create a tlkpAdult dimension table with a adt_today column populated with dates from 05/09/2017 to 12/31/2018, and updated adt_dob column using DATE(adt_today - 18 UNITS YEAR) to determine if person is >= 18 years old. I told the users they have until 12/31/2018 to upgrade to isql 7.50 on OpenSuSE platform, or the app will not work properly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine if the birthday has happened this year, you must be sure not to generate a non-valid date in the case where `dob` is *February 29* and `TODAY` is in a non leap-year. Since 2000 is a leap-year, you can avoid the problem making the subtraction always for the year 2000.

`MDY(MONTH(dob), DAY(dob), 2000) > MDY(MONTH(TODAY), DAY(TODAY), 2000)`

Finally, subtract one from the year difference if so:

`age = (YEAR(TODAY) - YEAR(dob) -
  CASE WHEN MDY(MONTH(dob), DAY(dob), 2000) > MDY(MONTH(TODAY), DAY(TODAY), 2000)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::int`